# Android Studio Lint check for Unnecessary Module Dependency

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, module, dependencies, lint

When running a Lint check on files in my project I often come across an error that looks like this (actual names of files redacted, but you'll get the idea):

> Dependency from module 'name_of_my_project' on module
>   'some_3rd_party_library' could be probably be removed when
>   complementary scope to 'File 'filepath_to_the_class_being_analyzed'
>   also does not contain references on module 'some_3rd_party_library'

I get this error for every single library that isn't compiled with Gradle - i.e. **libraries that have been imported whole into the project and then added as dependencies.**

Facebook is a great example of a library that even if you wanted to compile it through `Gradle` you couldn't because they don't support it, and you need to run it as a local library - it seems like you'll then receive this **"unnecessary module dependency"** warning for every class that doesn't directly call Facebook.

**So, the question is - what is the "proper" way of handling this error? Do I ignore it or am I supposed to change the code in some way to make it disappear?**

**Edit:** in the preferences menu for Lint it describes the check as follows (in case this helps figure it out):

> This inspection lists modules which contain redundant dependencies on
>   other modules. These dependencies can be safely removed.

Comment: I just ignore it :P Android studio inspections are full of crap anyways. But if someone comes up with a solution I'll be more than interested to know too :)

Answer (score 1):

There are known issues with the Lint checkers. I do not get this error in Android Studio 2.1.1. However, if you still do and you know it to be spurious, I would recommend going to Settings --> Editor --> Inspections --> Unnecessary Module Dependency and changing the Severity type from `Warning` to `Info`. This way you get a "clean lint build" and avoid a "broken windows" type of state due to bad lint algo. In fact, I've created a special category that has Info severity called `Info Due To Bad Lint Algo` to which I've assigned whatever I know to be spurious. This way I can periodically review those and see if they've been fixed.

You should report this to them btw, so there is some hope of it getting fixed... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid lint checking using following block of code.
Add following block of code into app build.gradle file inside android {}

`lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
        quiet true
        // if true, only report errors
        ignoreWarnings true
        abortOnError false
        disable "ResourceType"
    }`